# What does "torpedo a shot" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

The word "torpedo" usually means to destroy something with a torpedo. But in sports it seems to have a differet sense. So what does it actually mean?

61 min City 5 Saints 2
Walker drills a pass up to Foden by the D, an absolute daisy-cutter that Foden dummies and leaves for De Bruyne who takes it brilliantly in his stride before **torpedoing a low shot** past McCarthy.

Comment: Probably being used as a synonym for "firing" here

Comment: Please show some indication that you are thinking for yourself about these questions before you ask them here.

Comment: It is just colorful sports announcer/reporter language. That sentence is rich in similar uses of words that have a specific (or not necessarily so specific) meaning to eager followers of the sport: *drills*, *daisy-cutter*, *dummies*. All painting a vivid picture of what happened in the minds of fans.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen So, what does "torpedo" actually mean there? It's still unclear to me

Comment: @Jembot What Ryan M said. It would sound repetitive, uneducated even, if the sports announcer only ever used words like "shoots" and "kicks" when describing what a player does to the ball (or the puck - this could fit ice hockey as well as football). "Torpedoing" just means that the player put a lot of force into the kick as opposed to just gently nudging the ball. I'm sure there are other phrases with essentially the same meaning.

Comment: You have a lot of questions which are being downvoted. You need to take @ThePhoton advice to improve them as if you keep doing this then at some point the system will ban you from asking more questions. Apologies if you already knew that but you are in danger here.

Answer (score 1):

As someone said in the comments, it's basically colourful language - you're meant to understand it as *like a torpedo* or *in the manner of a torpedo*. I think the choice of metaphor is probably meant to carry a sense that the shot was

- fast and powerful
- low to the ground (like a torpedo just below the surface of the sea)
- dangerous (even if the player didn't score)

You're right that *torpedoed* usually means *sank*, in the sense of an impact which destroys something that had potential. But that doesn't really make sense in this context, so the *like a torpedo* reading seems right.

You can do this with any word really, if it evokes something figurative that makes sense in the context! *He just bananaed it!!!* isn't exactly standard English (and how do you spell it?), but you can probably work out what it means, y'know? Like a banana!